# moving tags inside a nav bar

Tags: html, css, django

How to move this 'TITLE' to the marked position using HTML and css. To the centre of the nav-links.
Please try to be elaborate as i;m just a beginner and this is for django websites. Thanks in advance :)[!
I found it a bit complicated to move things around and do stuff so please do let me out, this community is so helpful in making progress. Image is given

HTML CODE:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "portofolio/css/style.css" %}">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
{% block content %}
       <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>TITLE</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

CSS CODE:

```
*{  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
p {
     ;
}
.nav-link{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: baseline;
    min-height: 8vh;
    padding-top: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
.logo {
    color: rgb(226,226,226);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;;
}
.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-links a {
    color: rgb(226,226,226);
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Add `flex-direction: column` to `nav` in your CSS

Comment: does not align to the centre

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned your code for better responsiveness, hope it works for you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  min-height: 8vh;
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static " portofolio/css/style.css>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you don't want the wrapper then check the code now, it is the same HTML code of yours and I have modified the CSS. Hope it works.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot! since I am using office latpop and it blocks those softwares!

Comment: anyway to peronal message?

Comment: Tell me we can try to fix it here